# how to remove duplicate char from ARGB

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, argb

I am trying to get hex form rgb colors

```
public string GetCssValue(IWebElement iwe, string cssValue)
{
    var value = iwe.GetCssValue(cssValue);
    string[] numbers = value.Replace("rgba(", "").Replace(")", "").Split(",");

    int a = int.Parse(numbers[0]);
    int r = int.Parse(numbers[1]);
    int g = int.Parse(numbers[2]);
    int b = int.Parse(numbers[3]);

    Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);

    string hex = "#" + myColor.A.ToString("X2") + myColor.R.ToString("X2") + 
        myColor.G.ToString("X2") + myColor.B.ToString("X2");
```

here hex is gets the value #FFEEEE01 while my css on the page is #fee so that I can compare two strings (expected,actual)

how can I get the #fee as my hex value.
and what does this X2 represent here

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#XFormatString

Comment: `.Split(",")` does this compile? There is no overload that takes a single string argument in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: I'm not really sure that the out-of-the-box `ToString` will be able to do this. Seems like the 3 digit RGB format that CSS uses is "special".

Comment: Would you consider "expanding" the #fee value into the longer #ffeeee01 version during the comparison? Seems slightly easier than trying to do it the other way. But maybe it doesn't matter..

Comment: Also, I might be missing something here... The `Color` that gives the #FFEEEE01 value that you're getting is a yellow-ish color (A: 255, R: 238, G:238, B:1). That #fee CSS color is a  super light pink/red. Are they supposed to be the same? Or are they just 2 different examples?

Comment: Ah, I see what happened.. You're reading the colors as RGBA, but turning them into ARGB strings...

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to change your code to return the value would be to only concatenate the first character from the `RGB` values:

```
string hex = "#" + myColor.R.ToString("X2")[0] + myColor.G.ToString("X2")[0] + 
    myColor.B.ToString("X2")[0];
```

---

But, since only a subset of 6-digit codes can be accurately converted to 3-digit codes (only those with repeating characters), it might be helpful to write a helper method to convert the values:

```
public string GetThreeDigitRGB(Color color)
{
    // Get the 2-character RGB color codes
    var r = color.R.ToString("X2");
    var g = color.G.ToString("X2");
    var b = color.B.ToString("X2");

    // Every color must have a repeating character for its code, otherwise we return null
    return r[0] == r[1] && g[0] == g[1] && b[0] == b[1]
        ? $"#{r[0]}{g[0]}{b[0]}"
        : null;
}
```

Then your original code could be modified to create a `Color` object from the input and pass it to our helper method above to get the 3-digit code (also note the change where we get the color values in the order RGBA, which is how they're passed in):

```
public string GetCssValue(IWebElement iwe, string cssValue)
{
    var value = iwe.GetCssValue(cssValue);
    string[] numbers = value.Replace("rgba(", "").Replace(")", "").Split(",");

    // Note the change to get the colors in the correct order
    int r = int.Parse(numbers[0]);
    int g = int.Parse(numbers[1]);
    int b = int.Parse(numbers[2]);
    int a = int.Parse(numbers[3]);

    // Create a color from the values
    Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);

    // Call our helper method to get the three digit code from the color
    return GetThreeDigitRGB(myColor);
}
```